# Алгоритм обхода объектов

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Прошу помощи с выбором алгоритма для решения задачи, мне необходим только алгоритм.

Есть шар радиусом r, а также стена из шаров (препятствия) в трехмерном пространстве. Известны координаты и радиусы каждого из шаров, координаты страта основного шара, а также координаты, куда шар должен прилететь. Необходимо вывести координаты по которым должен пролететь наш шар, чтобы он не столкнулся с остальными. Какой алгоритм лучше использовать? Есть идея засунуть координаты в трехмерный массив и сделать обход.

[image: Основной шар - синий, остальные препятствия]

Comment: Вам нужно сначала выбрать подход к решению. А уж в какой массив засовывать координаты - это дело десятое. Что за "обход" вы собрались делать и как он поможет вам найти ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строите [диаграмму Вороного](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) по центрам зеленых кругов. Присваиваете каждому ребру вес, соответствующий ширине прохода. Выбираете маршрут по ребрам так, чтобы вес был больше веса шара.

[image: voronoi]

Comment: а как найти вес прохода?

Comment: @Vita Ну это просто - расстояние между точками, которые разделяет ребро, минус сумма радиусов соответствующих кругов. Каждое ребро состоит из точек, равноудаленных от каких-то двух центров.

Comment: @VVT тогда не очень понятно зачем строить диаграмму, можно поподробнее?

Comment: @Vita Чтобы узнать, какие круги как к друг другу прилегают. Концы ребер - это как раз те точки, через которые должен будет пройти основной круг.

Comment: Не забывайте только, что диаграмму Вороного придется строить в 3D.